GridSearch + StratifiedGroupKFold for continous target
I would like to perform a GridSearchCV() using a StratifiedGroupKFold for a dataset where the target y is continuous and my groups are only 2 :

Outlier
Not outlier

I kept having an error because my target is 'continous' but I would like to have the stratification on my group and not on the target. For example let's say I do 5 splits and I have 50 outliers, then I would like to keep 10 outliers only in each split. How can I do this ?
Here is the code I tried and of course I got an error :
cv = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=self._k)
groups = X_train['outlier'].to_numpy()

grid = GridSearchCV(
            pipe,
            grid_param,
            scoring=["neg_mean_squared_error", "r2"],
            cv=cv,
            verbose=0,
            refit="neg_mean_squared_error",
)
        
grid.fit(X_train, y_train, groups=groups)

Output :
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.

Knowing that the groups variable corresponds to an array containing only 0 and 1.
>> print(X_train['outlier])
116    0
86     0
53     0
225    0
647    0
      ..
75     0
112    0
280    0
450    0
108    1
Name: outlier, Length: 555, dtype: int64


"group" is sort of the opposite of "stratified", so this could use some clarification on what you want to happen in the splits.
